# Enumerated Type Width?

Tags: c#, c++, c, size, enumeration

Quick question. How wide are enumerated types? Are they of the minimum width required to represent the enumeration or are all enums ints? If they're ints, can you change the width of enums or would you have to type cast for each occurrence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This is for C++)

From the standard:

> The underlying type of an enumeration
>   is an integral type that can represent
>   all the enumerator values defined in
>   the enumeration. It is
>   implementation-defined which integral
>   type is used as the underlying type
>   for an enumeration except that the
>   underlying type shall not be larger
>   than int unless the value of an enumerator
>   cannot fit in an int or
>   unsigned int. If the enumerator-list
>   is empty, the underlying type is as if
>   the enumeration had a single
>   enumerator with value 0. The value of
>   sizeof() applied to an enumeration
>   type, an object of enumeration type,
>   or an enumerator, is the value of
>   sizeof() applied to the underlying
>   type.

In C++0x you can define the underlying type of an enum like follows:

```
enum foo : unsigned int { bar, baz };
```

Also note that the new strongly typed enums ("enum class") have a default underlying type of int.

Comment: Also note that any sane implementation wanting to facilitate libraries with stable ABI will not use types smaller than `int`, since adding new enumerators (e.g. in a new library version) could suddenly change the underlying type and break the interface.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ they're ints. Type casting will not change them in the slightest, unless you change them to a narrower integer type (char, short).

Comment: The underlying type is implementation-defined in C and C++03.

Comment: @Xeo, are you aware of any implementations that use anything other than `int`? Perhaps an embedded compiler...

Comment: In C (6.7.2.2/4) enums "are compatible with an integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined". Thus, `enum foo { A_FOO, ANOTHER_FOO, };` could, depending on the implementations, have `sizeof (enum foo) == 1` or `8` or anything allowing compatibility with an integer type of that implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This is different for the languages you tagged this question with.
In C and C++03, the underlying type of an enum is **implementation defined**. In C++0x, we can declare the underlying type ourselfs, called strongly typed enums (or enum classes):

```
// declares an enum with underlying type `unsigned char`
enum class MyEnum : unsigned char {/*...*/};
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can specify the underlying type, and if you don't specify then the default is `Int32`.

```
public enum ThirtyTwoBitsWide
{
    This, Is, The, Default, Size
}

public enum EightBitsWide : byte
{
    Explicitly, Specify, The, Underlying, Size
}
```